# Cannot convert value of type 'A<T>' to expected argument type 'A<_>'

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I created a generic class pretty much in the same way as bellow (don't pay attention to the purpose of the code, it's just to show the error)

I need to define what '+' means to two instances of the class A. Unfortunately, swift complains

> Cannot convert value of type 'A' to expected argument type 'A<_>'

for

```
public static func +(lhs: A<T>, rhs: A<T>) -> A<T> {
        return A.foobar(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, operation: +);
    }
```

And I have no idea why....

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

public struct A<T:Equatable&CustomStringConvertible> {

    public let uu:T

    public init(uu:T){
        self.uu = uu;
    }
}

extension A:Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: A<T>, rhs: A<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uu == rhs.uu
    }

    public static func +(lhs: A<T>, rhs: A<T>) -> A<T> {
        return A.foobar(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, operation: +);
    }

    fileprivate static func foobar(lhs: A<T>, rhs: A<T>, operation: (T, T) -> T) -> A<T> {

        return A<T>(uu:lhs.uu)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Edit:
to avoid confusion, foobar can be replaced by:

```
fileprivate static func foobar(lhs: A<T>, rhs: A<T>, operation: (T, T) -> T) -> A<T> {

    return A<T>(uu:operation(lhs.uu,rhs.uu))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real problem is that there is
no `+` operator of type `(T, T) -> T)` under the given restrictions.

One option might be to restrict `T` to conform to the [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) protocol,
which requires addition, subtraction and multiplication operators:

```
public struct A<T:Equatable & CustomStringConvertible & Numeric> { ... }
```

The standard integer and floating point types conform to this protocol.

Note also that inside `extension A` any reference to `A` without
generic placeholder  defaults to `A<T>`, so you can simplify the
code to

```
extension A: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uu == rhs.uu
    }

    public static func +(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> A {
        return A.foobar(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, operation: +);
    }

    fileprivate static func foobar(lhs: A, rhs: A, operation: (T, T) -> T) -> A {
        return A(uu: operation(lhs.uu, rhs.uu))
    }
}
```

Comment: mm... indeed, I missed this one... Is there something less restrictive that would allow +, * only? " -,/"  are not expected to exist for the type of T I'm looking for.

Comment: @Alex: I don't think so. You can define your own protocol (but then you must declare conformance of all needed types to that protocol explicitly). Note that division is *not* required in Numeric.

Comment: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md#proposed-solution for an overview of those protocols.

Comment: Yes, that's what it comes down to. Thanks a lot for your help, I'll count your post as valid answer. Can I ask you what made you think this was the problem? (besides that there was a problem with the def of '+')

Comment: @Alex: That is difficult to tell in retrospect. The error message made no sense (and the Fix-it did not fix it). First I removed all the unnecessary `<T>`, but that made no difference. Then I noticed that `+` must be of type `(T, T)->T`. To ensure that this is the problem, I tried `return A.foobar(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs, operation: { $1 })` and that compiled. – More or less a combination of intuition, experience, and try&error :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing Martin, I was also confused by the error message, and could not go past it. It's always good to know when the compiler has difficulties in making clear what it wants, hence my asking. have a great day!

Comment: @Alex: You may consider to *accept* the answer if it solved your problem :)